# Users can't save styles on the db PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database, and only with the PostgreSQL user (who's the owner of that table), I'm able to save styles to the database. I checked the user's permissions for the other group roles and all have SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE privileges over the layer styles table. So I really don't understand why they can't save the styles.

The group that I have is called r_readwrite and has USAGE in all schemas on the database and only SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE privileges in a couple of tables (one of them the layer_styles). The other group that I have is called r_readonly and only has SELECT privileges over all tables in the database.

[image: those are the privileges]

Does the group need to be set as the owner of the table to add styles? Maybe I'm missing something because once I changed the owner of the table from postgres to the group role it worked.

Comment: Styles are in the public schema? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91727/qgis-postgis-layer-styles

Comment: Be aware that the QGIS style table structure in PostGIS changes between QGIS 2.x and QGIS 3.x. So you can‘t read styles saved with QGIS 2.x in QGIS 3.x and vice versa.